# Passing objects as parameters to other objects - null

Tags: java

I'm building a railway simulator, with the classes simulator, station, train, route and passenger. I'm having a problem with passing a route object as a parameter to a train object - it keeps coming up as null. I've included my code as the best way to explain my problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Simulator {
int numStations;    
Route route1;
ArrayList<Station> stations;
ArrayList<Train> trains;
Route[] routes;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //set up network
    Simulator sim = new Simulator();                
    ArrayList<Station> stations = new ArrayList<Station>();
    stations = sim.generateStations();
    Route[] routes;
    routes = sim.generateRoutes(stations);
    System.out.println("Route array " + routes);
    ArrayList<Train> trains = new ArrayList<Train>();
    trains = sim.generateTrains(routes);

    //start simulator
    sim.generatePassengers(stations);
    Train currentTrain = trains.get(0);
    System.out.println("current train " + currentTrain);
    //route null here
    System.out.println("Route of current train " + currentTrain.route);


}


public Route[] generateRoutes(ArrayList<Station> stations){
    //initialise routes between stations

    Station[] stationList1 = {stations.get(0), stations.get(1), stations.get(2), stations.get(3), stations.get(4), stations.get(5)};
    int[] stationDist1 = {200,100,200,300,200,300};
    Route route1 = new Route(true, stationList1, stationDist1);
    System.out.println("route1 " + route1);

    //make list of all routes
    Route[] routeList;  
    routeList = new Route[1];
    routeList[0] = route1;

    return routeList;
}

public ArrayList<Train> generateTrains(Route[] routes){
    //initialise trains
    ArrayList<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<Train>();
    trainList.add(new Train(routes[0], 100, 0, true, 5));
    trainList.add(new Train(routes[0], 100, 4, false, 10));

    System.out.println("first train in list " + trainList.get(0));
    System.out.println("first route in array " + routes[0]);
    //route is null here
    System.out.println("route of first train " + (trainList.get(0)).route);

    return trainList;
}
}
```

Here is my output:

> route1 Route@addbf1
>
> Route array [LRoute;@42e816
>
> Route1 in array Route@addbf1
>
> first train in list Train@190d11
>
> first route in array Route@addbf1
>
> route of first train null
>
> current train Train@190d11
>
> Route of current train null

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Edit:
Train class declaration:

```
public class Train {
Route route;
int capacity;
int recentLoc;
boolean forwards;
boolean atStation;
int speed;
Train currentTrain;
int timeAtStation;

//train constructor
public Train(Route r, int c, int i, boolean f, int s){
    r = route;
    c = capacity;
    i = recentLoc;
    f = forwards;
    s = speed;
    atStation = true;
    timeAtStation = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is Train class declaration?

Comment: Could you show your Train constructor? The one called with "new Train(routes[0], 100, 0, true, 5)"

Comment: Show your `Train` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning values to your instance variables. Default value for object is null. Change "r = route" into "route = r" inside your Train constructor (the same for all the other fields).

```
public class Train {
Route route;
int capacity;
int recentLoc;
boolean forwards;
boolean atStation;
int speed;
Train currentTrain;
int timeAtStation;

//train constructor
public Train(Route r, int c, int i, boolean f, int s){
    route = r;
    capacity = c;
    recentLoc = i;
    forwards = f;
    speed = s;
    atStation = true;
    timeAtStation = 0;
}
```

Comment: same for all the other fields.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I did that before, can't believe I didn't notice myself doing it again, such a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
route = r; 
capacity = c;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues in your output.

First is that when you want to print conntent for array you must iterate through its elemnts, otherwise you just print the memory adress. To help you out hava API have method to that:

`Arrays.toString(Object[]);`

Same problem is in your `Train`, you do not override the `toString()` method, that is why Java print it address as this is its default behaviour.

Try to add this method to your route class and see what happen,

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return "This is message from rout"    
}
```

Ant the last in the construtor of Train

You assing the parameters to variable. You should do vice versa.

```
public Train(Route r, int c, int i, boolean f, int s){
    this.route = r;
    this.capacity = c;
    this.recentLoc = i;
    this.forwards = f;
    this.speed = s;
    this.atStation = true;
    this.timeAtStation = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the output was just for myself to try to work out what was wrong, so I didn't need it to be as strings, but I didn't know how to do that anyway, so I'm sure it'll come in handy some time :)

Answer (score 0):

These assignments should be the other way round, the thing on the left side is the thing getting assigned.

```
r = route;
c = capacity;
i = recentLoc;
f = forwards;
s = speed;
```

should be

```
 route = r;
   capacity = c;
   recentLoc = i;
    forwards = f;
    speed = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing assignments wrong.

```
r = route;
```

it means that value of `route` will be assigned to `r`.

Change you constructor to following:

```
public Train(Route r, int c, int i, boolean f, int s)
{     
     route = r;;     
     capacity = c;;     
     recentLoc = i;     
     forwards = f;     
     speed = s;     
     atStation = true;     
     timeAtStation = 0; 
}
```